# Undefined offset: 0: Laravel Error on LIVE Server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my Laravel Controller, I'm importing csv to my db, I query SQL get products_name and then insert product_name to my order table. The CODE work Perfect on my xampp server, it was when I deploy to live server (Cpanel) that I gives Error.

```
$products_name = DB::table('products_description')
->where('products_id','=', $importData[0])->pluck('products_name');


OrdersProduct::create(
                       array
                        (
                            "products_id"=>$importData[0],
                            "products_name"=>$products_name[0],
                            "products_quantity"=>$importData[1],
                        )
                    );
```

My Larevel Log is showing Error Msg: production.ERROR: `Undefined offset: 0`

When I used `return $products_name[0]`, It displays the Product Name... but when I tried to Create OrderProducts, it generates error. Note there is content is the products_name and it works fine on my localhost, only when I deployed to server I get error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404256/laravel-undefined-offset-0-collection-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Undefined offset 0 - collection.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404256/laravel-undefined-offset-0-collection-php)

Comment: You're certain that it should work on the live server because it worked and data is present on your local setup ? those two are unrelated. Have you checked the data on the live server too ? did you check the error line ?

Comment: Try `$products_name = DB::table('products_description')
->where('products_id','=', $importData[0])->first();` then use `$products_name->products_name` instead of `$products_name[0]`

Comment: Where does `$importData` come from?

Comment: you probably get your array with filter or something like it, you can use:
$myarray = array_values($myarray); to reindex your array,
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7558038/10573560

Comment: This exception is thrown when there is no value stored in a given index. This should be telling you that your SQL query returned `null` or `false`. You should check that the product name exists using `isset()`. If it should exist, then ensure your "live" server has the corresponding data to your localhost

Comment: @apokryfos $importData is from another query and it is working. This same issue happen even if I change the $importData to a static number.

Comment: @Jaquarh The Product name Exists, if I used to return, it will display the value, but when I tried to insert it to db is when it throw the error. The product name is Not null.

Comment: If you change `pluck('products_name')` to `value('products_name')` and then use `$products_name` (not an array) would that work?